# Flask local server exhibiting strange and fantastical behavior

Tags: python, flask, localhost

I'm developing a personal website in Flask and I'm noticing something odd about the way the local server has been working for me.

When I do the following:

```
$ export FLASK_APP=run.py
$ flask run
```

This message is displayed:

```
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger pin code: 262-302-085
```

That's all well and good. But when I actually go to `127.0.0.1:5000`, the server hangs and nothing ever happens. When I say 'hangs', I mean that the page stays blank but the loading icon indicates a successful connection, but the content of the site doesn't load. However, when I `CTRL+C` to close the script, then the website loads. Before doing so, it says the following:

```
^C * Serving Flask app "run"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/flask", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/cli.py", line 507, in main
    cli.main(args=args, prog_name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/cli.py", line 374, in main
    return AppGroup.main(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 697, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 1066, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 895, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 535, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/click/decorators.py", line 64, in new_func
    return ctx.invoke(f, obj, *args[1:], **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 535, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/cli.py", line 432, in run_command
    use_debugger=debugger, threaded=with_threads)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 708, in run_simple
    inner()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 670, in inner
    fd=fd)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 564, in make_server
    passthrough_errors, ssl_context, fd=fd)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 474, in __init__
    socket.SOCK_STREAM)
socket.error: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

I thought this was an error or something, so I `CTRL+C` and then I get back to my command line. I refresh the page, expecting the website to go down, and it's still there! Not only that, but the terminal has seemingly resurrected the process and is displaying HTTP 2xx status codes in the terminal as I move around the site and refresh pages. Strange. So I killed both chromium and my terminal and the website STILL loaded! So I deleted my cache for the last hour, restarted my laptop, and it was STILL up! It kind of quietly failed after another ten minutes, but I really don't understand what's happening here.

Can anyone show this confused lad some mercy? Because it doesn't seem like I should **have** to kill the script before the website loads. Something feels off, aside from the obvious. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong? I've been able to reproduce the problem and this has happened more than once now.

Thank you.

EDIT: Fixed a sentence and clarified that the problem is reproducible.